# iOS App keeps crashing for reviewer, but works fine in field tests

Tags: ios, swift, appstore-approval

my iOS app keeps crashing for the iOS reviewer team, but works fine on all kind of test flight devices (~10). I am unable to reproduce the problem.

The crash log the reviewer team sent me states

```
Incident Identifier: 6686BE5C-DCC1-48C1-9AC2-FCFF85F3EBC2
...
Version:             4 (2.1)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
...
Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x000000010012e218
Triggered by Thread:  5
...

Thread 5 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-qos
Thread 5 Crashed:
0   Alamofire                       0x000000010012e218 Alamofire.request (Alamofire.Method, Alamofire.URLStringConvertible, parameters : [Swift.String : Swift.AnyObject]?, encoding : Alamofire.ParameterEncoding) -> Alamofire.Request (Alamofire.swift:1522)
1   Alamofire                       0x000000010012e058 Alamofire.request (Alamofire.Method, Alamofire.URLStringConvertible, parameters : [Swift.String : Swift.AnyObject]?, encoding : Alamofire.ParameterEncoding) -> Alamofire.Request (Alamofire.swift:1522)
2   Stundenplan                     0x000000010009d4c4 function signature specialization <Arg[0] = Owned To Guaranteed> of Stundenplan.TimeTableManager.loadRemote (Stundenplan.TimeTableManager)() -> () (TimeTableManager.swift:103)
3   Stundenplan                     0x000000010009e434 Stundenplan.TimeTableManager.(reload (Stundenplan.TimeTableManager) -> () -> ()).(closure #1) (TimeTableManager.swift:58)
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000197b29990 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 20
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000197b29950 _dispatch_client_callout + 12
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000197b3677c _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 1844
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000197b37c48 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 104
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197d09228 _pthread_wqthread + 812
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197d08eec start_wqthread + 0
```

which seems to point to Alamofire, but I have not found a single report about anything even close to this.

I double checked my code for anything that could go wrong, but I still have no idea, why it keeps crashing.

```swift
func loadRemote() {
    if let timeTableName = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("timeTable") {
        // Prevent server flooding
        if let lastUpdate = lastUpdate where lastCourse == timeTableName {
            if NSDate.minutesBetween(date1: lastUpdate, date2: NSDate()) < 5 {
                return ;
            }
        }

        lastUpdate = NSDate()
        lastCourse = timeTableName

        let icalLink = "http://****/ical/\(timeTableName).ics"
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
        Alamofire.request(.GET, icalLink).responseString { (_, _, data, err) in
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
            if(err != nil) {
                PiwikTracker.sharedInstance().sendExceptionWithDescription("Server unreachable.", isFatal: true)
            } else {
                if let cache = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("icsCache") {
                    if data == cache {
                        return
                    }
                }
                TimeTable(icalString: data!, success: { (timeTable) in
                    self.currentData = timeTable
                    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(data, forKey: "icsCache")
                    }, error: {
                        println("error parsing timetable")
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you mark line 103 for us

Comment: I assume the problem is related to locale since you're using time and date. investigate into this. probably you need to set the locale yourself. otherwise it will use the device locale.

Comment: Line 103 is ``Alamofire.request(.GET, icalLink).responseString { (_, _, data, err) in``. See the first answer as a possible solution - Alamofire crashes when the string contains a space character.

Comment: No problems with the locale so far. I checked it before and the operations I am doing are pretty simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SIGTRAP` probably means an exception was thrown.

I can find [at least one instance in which AlamoFire could raise an exception](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/165). That was fixed last October. While it's possible you've not updated your copy of AlamoFire, I think the invalid characters in the URL clue is likely to be helpful given that you form the URL by directly pasting in a string from the user defaults.

I'd therefore suggest that the fix is to sanitise `timeTableName` during creation to only URL-safe characters.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was able to reproduce a exception by simply adding a space character in ``timeTableName``. I am not sure how they could create this error but this might be the source of the problem. I will resubmit the app now and see what happens. I will mark your answer as correct, as soon as the app gets approved.

Comment: Apple approved my app today. You were totally right. Thank you so much!